# Kendo Drop Down List Widget breaks when filter property set

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo drop down list tied to a remote data source. I've followed the documentation and configured virtualization and the remote data source is working as intended, but if the Filter option is set at all, bluring out of the open drop down throws an error in JS, and selecting anything throws an error in JS. The only way to close the list is clicking on the close arrow in the drop down widget.[image: drop down list arrow]

Below are screens of the errors i'm seeing in the console. 'Add' of undefined occurs when selecting an item:

[image: add of undefined]

'Attr' of undefined occurs when clicking outside of the drop down list to blur and close.

[image: attr of undefined]

I'm at a loss here. Any addition of the filter option causes these errors. I've isolated that as the issue by systematically removing every possible option and the only thing that seems to prevent the errors from occurring is the filter option:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
        .Name("MyDropDown")
        .DataTextField("MyText")
        .DataValueField("Id")
        .Filter(FilterType.Contains) //<--This guy right here
 ...
 ..more code..
 ...
 )
```

I've tried it in just JavaScript, I've tried it using the kendo ASP.NET MVC wrappers and the .ToClientTemplate option. I've tried it just using the MVC wrappers alone. I must be missing something but alas I do not see it.

EDIT: The issue seems to be happening in the close handler in kendo.all.js:

```
_closeHandler: function (e) {
            if (this.trigger(CLOSE)) {
                e.preventDefault();
            } else {
                this._focused.attr('aria-expanded', false);
                this.ul.attr('aria-hidden', true);
            }
        },
```

When it goes to set the aria-expanded to false on close, the _focused property is undefined. This happens before the close event, as I tried to hook into close to see if there is something in there I can manually correct. Is there any reason why this script isn't working? Am I missing a file? Everything appears to be configured correctly, but nevertheless, the widget is broken.

Edit #2: I thought maybe there was something wrong with the kendo libs, or some mismatch between libraries, or that this was possibly a bug in an older version, so I udpated my kendo libraries and the mvc wrapper to the newest version (2018.1.117) and the exact same issue is still happening. I thought maybe there was a mismatch in jquery version somehow that was causing the issue, but according to the documentation, version 2018.1.117 requires jQuery version 1.12.4, which i'm using. Just updated all the libraries and dependencies and i'm still getting the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In setting up an isolated test of the issue, I stumbled on to a line in a 3rd party script that was hijacking jQuery.fn.focus, which apparently had some serious side effects. Removing this line in the 3rd party script appeared to fix the issue entirely.

Comment: I searched for jQuery.fn.focus in my solution but there was no such line. But i am facing the same issue. Any solution yet ?

Comment: In my particular issue, the third party library was redefining jQuery.fn.focus, but there are a number of things that could be causing the symptoms I described above. Have you tracked down the issue to the _focused property being undefined in the _closeHandler function? If so, I would look for something a little more broad in your libraries, like $.fn.focus() or just .focus( and review the results, see if anything looks off. Unfortunately the symptoms are a misfire in the scripts and the errors that bubble up sometimes are not totally helpful in diagnosing the root cause.

Comment: Finally i found the root cause. The blur and focus event on input textbox in the multiselect dropdown was the issue in my plugin where i had extended the dropdown widget. I did not remove it as both the events has been put there intentionally. I have now put a check for a classname on the textbox  which was getting applied on expanding the dropdown. This has solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `.Filter("contains")`, might do the trick.